# Visual G : O que o caractere ' : ' significa e como ele influencia ou não nos resultados?

Tags: portugol, visualg

Estou aprendendo a usar o visual g por este material aqui: http://eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem2.htm

Neste código em especial eu tenho uma dúvida muito pequena, que não contém respostas nem no material e nem no google.

```
algoritmo "exemplo"
var x: real
y: inteiro
a: caractere
l: logico
inicio
x <- 2.5
y <- 6
a <- "teste"
l <- VERDADEIRO
escreval ("x", x:4:1, y+3:4) // Escreve: x 2.5    9
escreval (a, "ok")           // Escreve: testeok (e depois pula linha)
escreval (a, " ok")          // Escreve: teste ok (e depois pula linha)
escreval (a + " ok")         // Escreve: teste ok (e depois pula linha)
escreva (l)                  // Escreve: VERDADEIRO
fimalgoritmo
```

> O que eu não entendi é como x(2.5):4:1 é igual a 2.5 ? Tipo, o
>   caractere ' : ' não tem valor nenhum e por que os números 4 e 1?

Não entendi o que este caractere ' : ' significa e como ele influencia ou não nos resultados.

Comment: Achei a documentação confusa, preferi ver de qual linguagem foi baseado esse comportamento e olhe lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela documentação, o [visualg](/questions/tagged/visualg) está seguindo o modelo Pascal de escrita. Qualquer coisa, veja a [documentação em Pascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/write.html)

Quanto ao código: `x:4:1` significa quatro carácteres no máximo na saída, sendo que um depois da casa decimal; caso o número não preencha os quatro caracteres, põe espaços em branco. Na documentação do Freepascal linkada, a saída seria `2.5`, com um espaço à esquerda do número impresso.

Para ver o efeito, tente imprimir `5.3:7:2`, deve imprimir `5.30`. Três espaços antes do número, duas casas para decimais. Outro teste interessante é imprimir `5.29:3:1`, em que a saída (se arredondada) é `5.3`; três caracteres, uma única casa decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Como o colega afirmou acima, serve para limitar, por exemplo um número real muito grande, como em uma dízima periódica ou algo do tipo. O mesmo é feito em python. Todavia, VisualG é Pascal em português, assim a dica acima procede.

Sobre o 2,5. Ele aparece porque você armazenou ele na variável.